# How to get WiFi encryption mode on iOS/iPhone/iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi, mach

How to get Wi-Fi encryption mode in iOS without private libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code from the answer above has been posted originally on this website: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/621213/Non-Standard-Way-to-Get-Inaccessible-Data-from-iOS

By the way, for this code to work you need to include the appropriate header files with `#include <mach/mach.h>` so that your compiler recognizes `NDR_record_t ndr`.

However, this whole setup did not actually return me the encryption mode of the current WiFi, but rather the configuration of AirPort (the variable `key` in the code from above needs to be set to `NSString *key = @"Setup:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort";` before). I tried different values instead of AirPort which I got from running `$scutil` in the Terminal of my Mac (such as `Setup:/Network/Interface/en0/IPv4` or `Setup:/Network/Interface/en0/Modem` or  from [this website](https://00f.net/2011/08/14/programmatically-changing-network-configuration-on-osx/))

Hope that helps someone having similar issues...

Comment: what else I need to include apart from mach.h as I am getting **implicit declaration of function 'bootstrap_look_up2' is invalid in C99 **

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 5:

```
    aslmsg asl, message;
    aslresponse searchResult;
    int i;
    const char *key, *val;
    NSMutableArray *result_dicts = [NSMutableArray array];

    asl = asl_new(ASL_TYPE_QUERY);
    if (!asl)
    {
        DDLogCError(@"Failed creating ASL query");
    }
    asl_set_query(asl, "Sender", "kernel", ASL_QUERY_OP_EQUAL);
    asl_set_query(asl, "Message", "AppleBCMWLAN Joined BSS:", ASL_QUERY_OP_PREFIX|ASL_QUERY_OP_EQUAL);
    searchResult = asl_search(NULL, asl);
    while (NULL != (message = aslresponse_next(searchResult)))
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        for (i = 0; (NULL != (key = asl_key(message, i))); i++)
        {
            NSString *keyString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)key];

            val = asl_get(message, key);

            NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:val];
            [tmpDict setObject:string forKey:keyString];
        }
        [result_dicts addObject:tmpDict];
    }
    aslresponse_free(searchResult);
    asl_free(asl);
```

For iOS 6:

```
#define kMachPortConfigd "com.apple.SystemConfiguration.configd"

-(NSDictionary *)getSCdata:(NSString *)key
{

if(SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"6.0"))
{
    // It does not work on iOS 5.*
    return nil;
}

struct send_body {mach_msg_header_t header; int count; UInt8 *addr; CFIndex size0; int flags; NDR_record_t ndr; CFIndex size; int retB; int rcB; int f24; int f28;};

mach_port_t bootstrapport = MACH_PORT_NULL;
mach_port_t configport = MACH_PORT_NULL;
mach_msg_header_t *msg;
mach_msg_return_t msg_return;
struct send_body send_msg;
// Make request
CFDataRef  extRepr;
extRepr = CFStringCreateExternalRepresentation(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)(key), kCFStringEncodingUTF8, 0);

// Connect to Mach MIG port of configd
task_get_bootstrap_port(mach_task_self(), &bootstrapport);
bootstrap_look_up2(bootstrapport, kMachPortConfigd, &configport, 0, 8LL);
// Make request

send_msg.count = 1;
send_msg.addr = (UInt8*)CFDataGetBytePtr(extRepr);
send_msg.size0 = CFDataGetLength(extRepr);
send_msg.size = CFDataGetLength(extRepr);
send_msg.flags = 0x1000100u;
send_msg.ndr = NDR_record;

// Make message header

msg = &(send_msg.header);
msg->msgh_bits = 0x80001513u;
msg->msgh_remote_port = configport;
msg->msgh_local_port = mig_get_reply_port();
msg->msgh_id = 20010;
// Request server
msg_return = mach_msg(msg, 3, 0x34u, 0x44u, msg->msgh_local_port, 0, 0);
if(msg_return)
{
    if (msg_return - 0x10000002u >= 2 && msg_return != 0x10000010 )
    {
        mig_dealloc_reply_port(msg->msgh_local_port);
    }
    else
    {
        mig_put_reply_port(msg->msgh_local_port);
    }
}
else if ( msg->msgh_id != 71 && msg->msgh_id == 20110 && msg->msgh_bits <= -1 )
{
    if ((send_msg.flags & 0xFF000000) == 0x1000000)
    {
        CFDataRef deserializedData = CFDataCreateWithBytesNoCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, send_msg.addr,send_msg.size0, kCFAllocatorNull);
        CFPropertyListRef proplist = CFPropertyListCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, deserializedData, kCFPropertyListImmutable, NULL, NULL);
        mig_dealloc_reply_port(msg->msgh_local_port);
        mach_port_deallocate(mach_task_self(), bootstrapport);
        mach_port_deallocate(mach_task_self(), configport);
        mach_msg_destroy(msg);
        NSDictionary *property_list = (__bridge NSDictionary*)proplist;
        if(proplist)
            CFRelease(proplist);
        CFRelease(deserializedData);
        CFRelease(extRepr);
        return property_list;
    }
}
mig_dealloc_reply_port(msg->msgh_local_port);
mach_port_deallocate(mach_task_self(), bootstrapport);
mach_port_deallocate(mach_task_self(), configport);
mach_msg_destroy(msg);
CFRelease(extRepr);
return nil;
}
```

Comment: Does anyone know if this code will pass Apples' reviewing process?

Comment: Does there any way to get this information for OS X

Comment: @isox @chris\ conway I am getting: implicit declaration of bootstrap_look_up2 not allowed in C99... what is the fix for it?